# Cross-domain fonts don't work on a new domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I need to make a copy of a WordPress website for another domain. The main website (www) contains fonts and they must be shared between subdomains (different languages). The following code perfectly works on original website, but doesn't work on the new one.

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

For now both websites have 100% identical files and database, located on the same hosting, both use the same protocol (SSL) etc.

Why can this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You change to replace the code as mentioned in below,

```html
<ifmodule mod_headers.c="">
   SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.domain\.com)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
</ifmodule>
```

It Should be work !!

**For More Info:** There are multiple ways you could use Webfonts like @font-face or CSS3 methods, some browsers like Firefox & IE may refuse to embed the font when it’s coming from some non-standard 3rd party URL (like your blog) for same security reason.

**Get The More Info,** [enter link description here](https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-access-control-allow-origin-issue-for-your-https-enabled-wordpress-site-and-maxcdn/)

Good LUCK !!